# Paypal Api is not working for Tizen tv

Tags: paypal, tizen-web-app, tizen-tv

Paypal Rest Api is not working for Tizen tv while its working fine on rest client. 
Neither success nor failure function is called in Tizen tv.

Changed the url other than paypal its working fine. Also tried with ajax no changes found.

here is the sample code for it.

Get:

```
var request = $http({
    method : "get",
    url : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment",
    headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer A101.FfLKjOmGx-80JU9h9ACDqrm0-dSg5pvlUsMnz2Slsb9hbSZSNQXQ7c653uc0XEYS.dd1D0romSBOfYq_Q7dIh6KEQg0O"
    }
});
request.then(function(response){
console.log(response);

},function(error){
 console.log(error);

});
```

Post :

```
 var request = $http({
    method : "POST",
    url : 'http://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    data : 'grant_type=client_credentials',
    headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
            "Authorization": "Basic QWVRWnpOanM5UGdrQVdyb1VkbjktZ1lhcmNzNUxST2hSN2QyN1VTLTAyb0lXNy1pcmhyMUFkWXhLdkpoY1Q5Y0JoUXlxeHJDZW5MV2JXQjI6RUR4Q3pwbmRkRHBHSVI4SFo2TUR6dzkxYjR6enZndXgwc1hDSFhfU0c5c0pmOHFDNmg4NWd3S3ctTktIbW1ObXNtMFZpT0FQOU84WHREZFc="
    }
});
request.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);

  },function(error){
 console.log(error);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This API guide in Samsung D forum holds some examples that may help your query regarding Paypal.

[Samsung D forum API guide : https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen4791/index.html](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen4791/index.html)

If you still face issues, You may try posting in the SamsungDForum

[SamsungDForum Tizen TV: https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumDashBoard](https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumDashBoard/cd10341507013d28)

Thank you.